# Linq to SQL with INSTEAD OF Trigger and an Identity Column

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, triggers, identity

I need to use the clock on my SQL Server to write a time to one of my tables, so I thought I'd just use GETDATE(). The problem is that I'm getting an error because of my INSTEAD OF trigger. Is there a way to set one column to GETDATE() when another column is an identity column?

This is the Linq-to-SQL:

```
internal void LogProcessPoint(WorkflowCreated workflowCreated, int processCode)
{
    ProcessLoggingRecord processLoggingRecord = new ProcessLoggingRecord()
    {
        ProcessCode = processCode,
        SubId       = workflowCreated.SubId,
        EventTime   = DateTime.Now  // I don't care what this is. SQL Server will use GETDATE() instead.
    };

    this.Database.Add<ProcessLoggingRecord>(processLoggingRecord);
}
```

This is the table. EventTime is what I want to have as GETDATE(). I don't want the column to be null.

[image]

And here is the trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [Master].[ProcessLoggingEventTimeTrigger] 
   ON  [Master].[ProcessLogging]
   INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Master].[ProcessLogging] ON;

    INSERT INTO ProcessLogging (ProcessLoggingId, ProcessCode, SubId, EventTime, LastModifiedUser)
        SELECT ProcessLoggingId, ProcessCode, SubId, GETDATE(), LastModifiedUser FROM inserted

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Master].[ProcessLogging] OFF;
END
```

Without getting into all of the variations I've tried, this last attempt produces this error:

InvalidOperationException
Member AutoSync failure. For members to be AutoSynced after insert, the type must either have an auto-generated identity, or a key that is not modified by the database after insert.

I could remove EventTime from my entity, but I don't want to do that. If it was gone though, then it would be NULL during the INSERT and GETDATE() would be used.

Is there a way that I can simply use GETDATE() on the EventTime column for INSERTs?

Note: I do not want to use C#'s DateTime.Now for two reasons:
1. One of these inserts is generated by SQL Server itself (from another stored procedure)
2. Times can be different on different machines, and I'd like to know exactly how fast my processes are happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bob,

It seems you are attempting to solve two different problems here. One of which has to do with a L2S error with an Instead Of trigger and another with using the date on the SQL Server box for your column. I think you might have problems with Instead of Triggers and L2S. You might want to try an approach that uses an After trigger, like this. I think this will solve both your problems.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [Master].[ProcessLoggingEventTimeTrigger] 
ON [Master].[ProcessLogging]
AFTER INSERT

AS 
BEGIN
UPDATE [Master].[ProcessLogging] SET EventTime = GETDATE() WHERE ProcessLoggingId = (SELECT ProcessLoggingId FROM inserted)
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a trigger, use a defualt:

```
create table X
(id int identity primary key,
value varchar(20),
eventdate datetime default(getdate()))

insert into x(value) values('Try')
insert into x(value) values('this')

select * from X
```

It's much better.

Comment: If you can usea default, it is almost always preferable to using a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a default value of (getdate()) for the EventTime colum?
You wouldn't then need to set the value in the trigger, it would be set automatically.

A default value is used when you don't explicitly supply a value, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO ProcessLogging (ProcessLoggingId, ProcessCode, SubId, LastModifiedUser)
    SELECT ProcessLoggingId, ProcessCode, SubId, LastModifiedUser FROM inserted
```

[image]

Comment: That's what I wanted to do, but the problem is the ID column. I get different errors. Let me try your *exact* scenario.

Comment: I get this error when I try your suggestion: Member AutoSync failure. For members to be AutoSynced after insert, the type must either have an auto-generated identity, or a key that is not modified by the database after insert.

Comment: I see, your problem is because you are explicitly setting the primary key and overriding the auto-increment.  Linq to SQL is getting confused.  Can you remove the trigger completely?

Comment: I could, but then the default value would only get used when the property on the class is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Bob,

I see it is better to don't use triggers in SQL server; it have a lot of disadvantage and not recommended for database performance enhancements. Please check SQL Authority blog for more information about the [Triggers problems](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/24/sql-server-disadvantages-problems-of-triggers/).

You can achieve what you want without Triggers using the following steps:

1. Change Eventime column to allow null
2. Set Eventtime column Default Value to GetDate(). So it always will have a the current insertion value.
3. Don't set Eventtime value to DateTime.Now from your LinqToSQL code, so it will take the default value in the SQL Server.